# A few doubts on my C program to check prime

Tags: c, return, primes

This is a simple function to check whether the given number is prime or not and works for the most part except for 2 and 3 (as it doesn't enter the for loop) but they are already prime so no checking is required and the flag should remain untouched.But notice how I put the return statement inside the for loop(This was by mistake) so for integers 2 and 3 as they do not enter the loop the function should return 0(or so I assumed) but they always return 1.why? Is it because the program terminated incorrectly? then why always 1? it can be any non-zero integer right?and are there cases where the main() itself returns a 1?.Please clarify my doubts.Dev-C++ is the IDE used and it uses tdm-gcc 4.9.2 compiler.

```
int checkPrime(int n)
{
    int i, isPrime = 0;

    for(i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            isPrime = 1;
            break;
        }  
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: On https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test there is a better algorithm, with loop that stops at sqrt(n) instead of n/2 and i which increases by 6, not by 1.

Comment: Move "return isPrime;" down and outside the for loop.

Comment: Indentation fail.  Good formatting is not just for looking pretty:(

Comment: Note that stepping through with your debugger would have immediately demonstrated the problem:(

Comment: You already know that "return statement inside the for loop(This was by mistake)". It still is a mistake. If you are asking about something else, why don't you edit your question in order to make people focus on the problem you actually want to discuss?

Answer (score 0):

On x86 architecture, the return value of function is in `%eax` register.

Value present there would be regarded as the return value of the function `checkPrime`.

And in the `%eax` register, the value present would be '1', so '1' was treated as the return value.

Proof (Passing '2' to `checkPrime()` and at the end `eax` holds 1):-

```
Dump of assembler code for function checkPrime:
   0x0000000000400526 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400527 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040052a <+4>: mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x000000000040052d <+7>: movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400534 <+14>:    movl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053b <+21>:    nop
   0x000000000040053c <+22>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040053f <+25>:    mov    %eax,%edx
   0x0000000000400541 <+27>:    shr    $0x1f,%edx
   0x0000000000400544 <+30>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x0000000000400546 <+32>:    sar    %eax
   0x0000000000400548 <+34>:    cmp    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040054b <+37>:    jl     0x400568 <checkPrime+66>
   0x000000000040054d <+39>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400550 <+42>:    cltd   
   0x0000000000400551 <+43>:    idivl  -0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400554 <+46>:    mov    %edx,%eax
   0x0000000000400556 <+48>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400558 <+50>:    jne    0x400563 <checkPrime+61>
   0x000000000040055a <+52>:    movl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400561 <+59>:    jmp    0x400568 <checkPrime+66>
   0x0000000000400563 <+61>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400566 <+64>:    jmp    0x400568 <checkPrime+66>
   0x0000000000400568 <+66>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400569 <+67>:    retq   

(gdb) break *0x0000000000400569
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400569: file ./test.c, line 19.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/syed/Desktop/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400569 in checkPrime (n=2) at ./test.c:19
19  }

(gdb) info registers eax
eax            0x1  1
```

Comment: does eax register store 1 as default?

Comment: @Ganesh Thampi. The eax does not hold '1' by default. Initially eax contains some garbage value but at `0x0000000000400548 <+34>: cmp    -0x4(%rbp),%eax `  the `eax` changes its value to 1.  `(gdb) ni
0x000000000040053c 10   for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
(gdb) info registers eax
eax            0x40056a 4195690
0x0000000000400548 10   for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
(gdb) info registers eax
eax            0x1 1
`

Comment: Let me know if your question has been answered. Thanks

Comment: @Ganesh -- My advice is not to rely on this answer. The fact of the matter is what you are experiencing is undefined behavior. And that's really where the discussion should end IMO. Because one particular compiler on one particular architecture under one particular set of optimizations on one particular input source file chooses to return a 1 instead of any other behavior is irrelevant. Because when you add code, delete code, update your compiler, or recompile with different optimization levels you may find that "working" code no longer works at all. That's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is in wrong place. You should put it out of `for` loop. And also in programming 1 stands for true and 0 for false, so you are asking if n is prime and for 17 your function returns 0 (false), but it is prime:

```
int checkPrime(int n)
{
    int i, isPrime = 1;

    for(i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            isPrime = 0;
            break;
        }  
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```